# How to prove this summation involving Legendre symbol: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1}k\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)=0 $

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

> If $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ is a prime number, prove that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\biggl(\dfrac{k}{p}\biggr)=0 $$

Any suggestion how to prove it I will appreciate.

Comment: Remember that $$\biggl(\dfrac{k}{p}\biggr)\equiv k^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p$$

Answer (score 2):

may help to note that
$$
(p-k)^2 = p^2 -2kp + k^2 \equiv k^2 \mod{p}
$$

Answer (score 2):

For an odd prime $p$, exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ of the numbers $1\leq k\leq p-1$ are quadratic residues (apply the first isomorphism theorem to the homomorphism $\mathrm{sq}:(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times\to(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ defined by $\mathrm{sq}(x)=x^2$).

For a prime $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and any $1\leq k\leq p-1$, $k$ is a quadratic residue iff $p-k$ is a quadratic residue (use the fact that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$).

Thus, there are $\frac{p-1}{4}$ pairs $(k,p-k)$ of quadratic residues among the numbers between $1$ and $p-1$, and also $\frac{p-1}{4}$ pairs $(k,p-k)$ of non-quadratic residues.

Comment: What do we need for showing $-1$ is a quadratic residue ? I was thinking to $-1 \equiv g^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$ where $g$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$

Comment: @user1952009: That's certainly sufficient to show $-1$ is a quadratic residue. David Holden's answer essentially describes another way to see this, also.

Comment: I don't get how it shows $-1$ is a square